How to open dropdown menu from outside button
Opening bootstrap dropdown menu from button inside table using


function xonclick() {
  const dropdownButton = document.getElementById('settingsDropDown');
  const dropdownMenu = document.getElementById('seadedMenyy');
  
  // Position the dropdown near the clicked button
  const clickedButton = document.getElementById('grid_muu');
  const buttonRect = clickedButton.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  dropdownMenu.style.position = 'absolute';
  dropdownMenu.style.left = buttonRect.left + 'px';
  dropdownMenu.style.top = (buttonRect.bottom + 2) + 'px';
  
  // Create and show dropdown
  const dropdown = new bootstrap.Dropdown(dropdownButton);
  dropdown.show();
}
#settingsDropDown {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
 
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
<button id="settingsDropDown" class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown button
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="seadedMenyy">
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>

  <table>
<tr>
  <td>Some text</td>
  <td><button id="grid_muu" onclick="xonclick()">Open menu</button></td>
</tr>
  </table>
</body>



does not open it. Clicking in "Open menu" button does nothing.
How to open dropdown menu near this button if button is clicked?
Dropdown is defined in other place in DOM and display is set to none.

Are there any errors in your console? Are you including popper.js or bootstrap.bundle.js, per the documentation?

@mukaf: Full bootstrap bundle is included which contains also popper. Tere are no errors in console.
